# Clojure style: defn- vs. letfn

Tags: clojure, coding-style

Clojure style (and good software engineering in general) puts emphasis on lots of small functions, a subset of which are publicly visible to provide an external interface.

In Clojure there seem to be a couple of ways to do this:

```
(letfn [(private-a ...)
        (private-b ...)]
  (defn public-a ...)
  (defn public-b ...))

(defn- private-a ...)
(defn- private-b ...)
(defn public-a ...)
(defn public-b ...)
```

The letfn form seems more verbose and perhaps less flexible, but it reduces the scope of the functions.

My guess is that letfn is intended only for use inside other forms, when little helper functions are used in only a small area. Is this the consensus? Should letfn ever be used at a top level (as I've seen recommended before)? When should it be used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`letfn` is intended for use in cases of mutual recursion:

```
(letfn [(is-even? [n]
          (if (zero? n)
            true
            (is-odd? (dec n))))
        (is-odd? [n]
          (if (zero? n)
            false
            (is-even? (dec n))))]
  (is-even? 42))

;; => true
```

Don't use it at the top level.

Also don't use the `defn` macro anywhere else than at the top level unless you have very specific reasons. It will be expanded to the `def` special form which will create and intern global var.

Comment: Do you feel that `letfn` is not generally appropriate for helper functions in general--one use user2494739 mentioned--but only for mutual recursion?  I don't have any feel for what's commonly done with `letfn`, so I may be idiosyncratic, but I often define helper functions using `letfn`, or sometimes `(let [f (fn [x] ...) ...]` to avoid using `let` and `letfn` together.

Comment: I think using `letfn` or `(let [f (fn [x] ...` like that is fine. I do that all the time myself. It reduces the number of functions you have defined at the top level, which I view as a good thing.

Comment: To clarify, though, I use `letfn` *within* a `defn`. Something like `(defn top-level-fn [xs] (letfn [(helper [y] (do-something-with y))] (map helper xs)))`

Comment: Right--same here, @DaveYarwood.  I guess I wouldn't mind so much having an additional top-level function, per se, but `letfn` makes it obvious that it's *just* there as a helper for the `defn`ed function, and *that* is a good thing, in addition to reducing the number of top level functions.

Comment: I use `letfn` only in cases of mutual recursion. In all other cases `(let [f (fn ...` suffices and offers more binding possibilities.

Comment: Definitely nothing wrong with using `letfn` for general helper functions, including at the top level. One example of this in the wild is Pedestal's [dataflow engine](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal-app/blob/master/app/src/io/pedestal/app/dataflow.clj#L46). I'm not affiliated - just a random example from a "serious" project by credible Clojure folks.

Comment: @jbm Even though the example was written by "credible Clojure folks" I don't consider it good style: 1. The only purpose it serves is making it clear to a human reader that those two functions are only used in the `defn` form of its body. 2. E. g. a code analysis tool that relies on the source metadata of the function to display source in an IDE will be stuck resolving the two fns.

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of `letfn` is totally different from the purpose of `defn` form. Using `letfn` at the top level does not give you same properties of defn, since any bindings of names to functions bound inside `letfn` is not visible outside its scope. The binding for functions bound inside `let` or `letfn` is not available outside its lexical scope. Also, the visibility of functions bound inside `letfn` is independent of the order in which they are bound inside that lexical scope. That is not the case with `let.`

Comment: @Thumbnail Vars was a wrong term to use. I tried to fix the terms.

Answer (score 4):

My rules are these:

- If a subsidiary function is used in *one* public one, define it
  locally with `let` or `letfn`.
- If it is used in several, define it at top level with `defn-`.

And

- Don't use `let` or `letfn` at top level.
- Don't use `def` or `defn` or `defn-` anywhere other than top level.

Comment: I use a channel to allow communication between a couple of private functions and my main function and use:
`(let [c (chan)]
    (defn- a ...)
    (defn- b ...)
    (defn -main (a ...) (b ...)))`
would that not be good?

Comment: @peter I wouldn't say it's too bad if you REALLY need that mutability and statefulness. Be warned, it will cause problems with concurrency.